# Executing query by reading from excel cell

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oracle

Usually, we connect to an Oracle DB through C# and then execute queries through C#. But, I have an excel sheet. In that excel sheet, under F cell, I write my query in a cell. I have stored the value of this cell as strParam1. Declaration is as follows:

```
String strParam1 = Convert.ToString(xlRange.Cells[row, 6].Value);
```

I wish my program to read that cell and execute whatever query is written under that cell i.e. I want my code to read strParam1 and execute the query. How is fetching and executing query statements done using excel sheet here?

Posting my code

```
public void UpdateDatabase()
        {
            System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection conn = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.5.144)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl)));UID=mwm;PWD=mwm";
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Select * from \"Task\"";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but can't you just do `command.CommandText = strParam1;`?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez  in that cell, I give my query Select * from Task   But it throws an exception "invalid character"

Comment: When you're asking a question on SO, please post the error and stack trace whenever you get an error. Also, `ExecuteNonQuery` is pretty useless if you're running a `SELECT`. You should use [`ExectuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab4kxd8h) so that you can read the results of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question, which seems so simple that I think I've not, this is all you're trying to do

```
public void UpdateDatabase()
        {
            System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection conn = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.5.144)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl)));UID=mwm;PWD=mwm";
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = strParam1;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: in that cell in the excel sheet, I give my query Select * from Task    But it throws an exception "invalid character"

Comment: I dont know...in that cell, I typed Select * from Task   but it throws dis exception...i also tried Select * from Task;   then also, it throws same exception

Comment: I'm not fully sure how it will react to having a Select query being executed as a NonQuery. Sounds like more of an issue with your SQL than your C#. Try running the command directly in SQL and see what happens. But the fact you're doing a Select may cause problems

Comment: I edited the code as 
conn.Open();
                OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
               // command.CommandText = strParam1;
                command.CommandText = "Select * from \"Task\"";
                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                command.Dispose();
Now, I am able to see the results. I use OracleDataReader. But, if i give strParam1 as u said and type the same query in excel sheet cell, I get exception

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` with SELECT is not a problem, although pretty useless. There must be something wrong with the SQL.

Comment: When you write the query in excel make sure you remove the forward slashes (\\) first. In C# they are escaping the proceeding quotes, but when reading it in excel, you wont need to do that